# Why is eval unsafe in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why exactly is eval evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil)

I read people claim that eval is unsafe when run on arbitrary user input code. I understand this in other languages that run on the server that access the filesystem, etc. However, why does this matter when executing code in a browser? After all, can't you just fire up Firebug and write any arbitrary script you want anyway? So then how is eval any different?

Comment: `eval()` may be a XSS attack vector, if you're not careful

Comment: please explain a little further

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826859/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-eval

Comment: @Joel: You can check about XSS here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/27/preventing-cross-site-scripting-attacks . It explains how eval is not safe and vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @Phrogz, only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil is relevant - the others are about eval in general, this is a very different question (cause other languages are not generally run in a sandbox)

Comment: @Phrogz, Having read it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil is asking the same question but none of the answers as far as i am concerned actually answer the question well in the context of JS

Comment: Why was this closed? The linked "possible duplicate" is about Lisp eval whereas this one is about JavaScript eval. And the other questions linked in the comments are asking "when is eval safe" which IMHO is not the same as "why is eval unsafe".

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. This is specifically about JavaScript, where the threats posed by `eval` in server-side languages often don't apply, because JavaScript doesn't have io access.

Answer (score 19):

The danger of `eval` only rears its ugly head when you are serving a script written by alice to user bob for bob's browser to eval.

e.g. if bob enters his password on your page, alice could have written a keylogger in the user input you `eval`ed and arrange for the data to be encoded in a script that bob will (unknowingly) submit to be served to alice. This is, as @Hunter2 has suggested in the comments, an XSS attack.

If you are not serving to other people, you are correct in assuming it is equivalent to firing up firebug

Answer (score 1):

don't think it is unsafe, for the most paranoid execute `eval = null;`

Comment: This won't help.  I can get most of the authority of `eval` by doing `new ((function () {}).constructor)('alert("Untrusted code")')()`.  Look Ma, no globals!

Comment: that made `window` go all bonkers on me, but I'm curious: if you'd override a reference to a native through `window`, is there any way you can reference it otherwise?

Comment: `function myEval(str){return (new Function(str))()}` is simpler and works for me :D

Comment: What's the danger of this, besides evalled code throwing something?