# How to get data from json array in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have php function, that returns array to JavaScript like this:

```
    $data['first'] = 10;
    $data['second'] = 20;
    echo json_enocde($data);
```

In JavaScript the returned value is named response. I need to display the values and tried like this after reading about json:

```
        alert("First: " + response.first + " Second: " + response.second);
```

But this code only shows undefined values in places of response.first and response.second.
If I write alert(response), then I get answer:

```
{"first":"10","second":"20"}
```

This means, that JavaScript is getting the information. 
How can I get the values separately from the json encoded array?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` to turn the JSON string into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you still have the JSON string, and not parsed it to an JS object. Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var jsonString = '{"first":"10","second":"20"}'; // from whereever
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert("First: " + response.first + " Second: " + response.second);
alert(obj); // should now be "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score -2):

use eval like (NOT RECOMMENDED)

```
var res = eval(response); //as you can see people are against it so I am editing the answer
```

USE
    JSON.parse()

OR if you use jquery

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `eval`. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812288/why-is-eval-unsafe-in-javascript for details

Comment: `eval()` like that will mistake the braces as a block definition.