# It this javascript function possible?

Tags: javascript

When debugging I often write something like `console.log("foo:"+foo+", bar:"+bar)` is it possible to write a function `logValues(foo,bar)` which would give the same output? Essentially I'm asking if there is a way to go from a variable to that variable's name. Do I have to setting for looping for an arguments array just using the index yielding  `[0]: 'value of foo, [1]: 'value of bar'`

Thanks for reading

Comment: You want to output in the console or directly in your page?

Comment: A variable can be known by more than one name.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Two variables can hold the same value, but one variable cannot have two names.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, Unless you pass an array `["foo","bar"]`.

Comment: @Derek What do you mean? When you pass an array to a function, that array will be the value of the corresponding named argument.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I mean you can pass two names in one single argument using an array, so that you can loop through it.

Comment: @Derek Those are not names. Those are merely string values. We were talking about variable names, and how one variable cannot have two names. This is unrelated.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, Ok, I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
var logValues = function(){
    var args = arguments;
    for(var i in args)
        window.console.log(args[i] + ": " + eval(args[i]));
}
logValues("foo","bar");
```

Comment: I was about to put something like that but couldn't remember the syntax. Darn. Had everything but finding the argument's name.

Comment: I was about to answer it but when I start your answer showed up.

Comment: YEs, you have to take care about eval, but if I'm not wrong, this is the best way

Comment: You have to make sure that "foo" and "bar" are declared in the same scope of this function. Otherwise, this is not gonna work

Comment: @MarkLinus Your answer is not a solution to OP's problem, since he wants to invoke the function like so: `logValues( foo, bar );`. My point is that the OP does *not* have the string names, but only the variable names.

Comment: So he has to call the logValues function like this: `for(var i in objectThatStoresTheVars) logValues(i)`

Comment: @MarkLinus Variables and arguments are stored in the environment record of a lexical environment. Such an environment record cannot be accessed by a program. (So, it is not possible to perform a `for-in` loop on it.)

Comment: -1 from me to counter the upvotes. It won't work generally, it will only work in a specific case. Hence it is an unnecessary use of `eval`. Parameters are passed by value, not by name, you can't work backwards from the value to the name because there is no mechanism in ECMAScript to do that, and more than one variable can hold the same value.

Answer (score 2):

(none of these options directly answer the question; but should give better alternatives for what you're trying to do)

**WebKit's inspector (and I assume Firebug) allow you to log complex types, no need to write helpers at all!**

Just `console.log(foo, bar)` and you're set.  Or `console.log({foo: foo, bar: bar})` if you want the variable names in the output.

[image]

**Alternative Answer:**

You might consider a helper that just takes an object and spits it out - it doesn't save much, if any, typing; but results in more readable code that pretty closely matches the logged output.

```
window.logValues = function(values) {
  var k, v;
  var pairs = [];

  for (k in values) {
    v = values[k];
    pairs.push("" + k + ": " + v);
  }

  console.log(pairs.join(", "));
};
```

You then call it like:

```
logValues({foo: 1, bar: "asdf"})
```

To which you see:

```
foo: 1, bar: asdf
```

**Option #3:**

Or a more terse example that may strip out a little more type information than you like:

```
window.logValues = function(values) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

Comment: This answer demonstrates that it is possible to retrieve the names of the properties of an object (as strings), unlike variables and arguments for which is it not possible to retrieve their names as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
function logValue(foo)
{
    console.log(foo + ": " + eval(foo));
}

var foo = "something";
logValue("foo");
```

This will work, but you have to make sure that your foo variable is available inside the logValue function.

Comment: You can't do `logValues("foo","bar")` on this one.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it shows in a simple way how to evaluate and log the value of a variable from its name represented with a string. I hope and expect that he's able to modify this with a for loop.

Comment: @RasmusTaulborgHummelmose As I already stated in a comment above, this type of answer is not a solution to OP's problem, since the OP wants to invoke the function like so: `logValue( foo );`. The OP wants to pass a variable into that function, not a string representing the name of that variable.

Comment: So is it possible to get the string representation of a variables name? It is the closest I can get to what he wants. After all it's just a convenience method anyways.

Comment: @RasmusTaulborgHummelmose I don't think it's possible. (There might exist a non-standard way to do it.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, If you do it like that, it won't able to get the name.

Comment: @Derek Well, yeah, that's what I've been saying in my other comments here.

Answer (score 0):

I use two arrays to store all data in:

```
data=[];
names=[];
foo=1;
data[1]="foovalue"; 
names[1]="foo";

bar=2;
data[bar]=28;
names[bar]="bar";
```

etcetera, all global values that I use in a project
Next you can write code like

```
data[foo]=data[foo] + data[bar];
data[bar]=data[bar]+22;

function log(a,b){
//something like
var=text;
text=names[a] + " = " + data[a];
text=text + linebreak + names[b] + " = " + data[b];
}
```

you can also use it to write to html;

```
function writedataval(arrnumber){
  document.getElementById(names[arrnumber] ).innerHTML =  data[arrnumber] ;
}

writedataval(foo);
```

There has to be a tag with id="foo" before you can run this code succesfully

I think this approach very beneficial in many ways as you can also use the array indexes to acces data and name .