# How to execute a code encoded in base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I have this code in an html page (JavaScript):

```
<script>
    var cox,d = 0;
    Console.Log(cox,d);
</script>
```

Now I encrypted `[var cox,d = 0; Console.Log(cox,d);]` manually with base64 encode and the result is this: `IHZhciBjb3gsZCA9IDA7DQogQ29uc29sZS5Mb2coY294LGQpOw==`

I want that this encoded string (the code) could be executed by another JavaScript function in the same page... example:

```
<script>
    var encoded = "IHZhciBjb3gsZCA9IDA7DQogQ29uc29sZS5Mb2coY294LGQpOw==";
    var decodedString = atob(encoded);
    /* Problem is here */
</script>
```

I want to execute the JavaScript code (encoded above) in `/* Problem is here */` '.

How can I do?

Comment: Just being pedantic, encoding with BASE64 and encrypting is not the same thing at all. I think you want to use `eval` - but that is a slippery slope :)

Comment: You know that `Console` != `console`

Comment: my pc changed it from console to Console automatically because I coded it on stack overflow not on an editor first....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function [(it is not recommended)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474424/6512354), but it solves your problem.

```js
/* var cox,d = 0; console.log(cox,d); */
var encoded = "dmFyIGNveCxkID0gMDsgY29uc29sZS5sb2coY294LGQpOw==";
var decodedString = atob(encoded);


eval(decodedString);
```

Another way of doing it, is using the [New Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```js
/* var cox,d = 0; console.log(cox,d); */
var encoded = "dmFyIGNveCxkID0gMDsgY29uc29sZS5sb2coY294LGQpOw==";
var decodedString = atob(encoded);

var func = new Function(decodedString);
func();
```

*When encodeding your code, Console and Log must be lowercase and not ucfirst.

I am not a security expert, and I truely advice you to check the risks of evaluating and executing this kind of functions in your apps.

[Here is an interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599946/6512354) about the difference between `eval` and `new Function`

Comment: Thank you very much... The second works properly for me and is what I was looking for...