# How will i convert this string consist of two or more numbers and a arithmetic operator into integers with working operators

Tags: javascript

How will i convert this string consist of two or more numbers and a arithmetic operator into integers with working operators. I trying for a while

```
let a = "45+55";
console.log(parseInt(a));
```

I want the answer with addition but it prints the first value.

Expected value

```
//100
```

Value i am getting

```
//45
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can use `eval("45+55")`, but it is [infamous and notorious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474306/whats-the-main-benefit-of-using-eval-in-javascript).

Comment: is there a pattern like value operator value operator?

Comment: @HassanImam **thanks Man!**

Answer (score 0):

The `eval()` will execute a **String**.
it will fork a new thread and **Interpret Commands presented in String**
You can use it like this:

```
eval("45+55")
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue can be resolved using eval, but as Hassan has already mentioned, eval can be very [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474306/whats-the-main-benefit-of-using-eval-in-javascript).

What you can do is create a function that parses the strings and does the operation:

```js
function arithmetic(str) {
    // Probably want to remove all spaces here, but I won't do that now lol

    // Get the numbers based on whether there's a `+-/*` in the string
    const numList = str.split(/[+-/*]/i);
    const num1 = parseFloat(numList[0]);
    const num2 = parseFloat(numList[1]);

    // Create the regex to find the arithmetic operator
    const regex = new RegExp(/[+-/*]/i);

    // Run the correct operation on the numbers
    switch(regex.exec(str)[0]) {
        case '+':
            console.log(num1 + num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            console.log(num1 - num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            console.log(num1 / num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            console.log(num1 * num2);
            break;
        default:
            console.error('Operation not found');
            break;
    }
}
```

You can even extend this code to do more complicated math, but hey that's up to you and whether you want to.