# Using eval() in python to add numbers

Tags: python, eval

I want to let user enter string such as `2+5-3+6` and return `10`. If user enter `c` then answer will be printed. I don't know how to make the project break when user enter a `c`.

```
print 'This is a calculator. Please follow the instruction.'

temp = 0
string = 0

def asmd(string):
    print 'Your answer is', eval(str(string))

while temp != 'c':
    print 'Please enter a number or operation. Enter c to complete. :'
    temp = raw_input()
    string = str(string)+str(temp)

    if temp == str('c'):
        asmd(string)
```

Comment: `eval` is dangerous, it can easily be used to inject code into your script for undesired consequences. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826859/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-eval?rq=1

Comment: @InbarRose: Good article by Ned Batchelder on the topic: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 1):

To fix the calculator, just make sure the ending character (`c`) doesn't end up in your result string:

```
if temp == str('c'):
    asmd(string[:-1])
```

I have to note though that the whole script is pretty crazy. You are using `eval`, which can evaluate complete expressions at once, but still you instruct users to enter them one-by-one. With eval, you can rewrite your whole script in one line:

```
print eval(raw_input())
```

Also as extensively pointed out in the comments, it is generally bad idea to use `eval` in case you don't trust the user running your calculator. If you are just practising then fine -- just don't use `eval` in "real code".

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to practice how to end the calculation if user enter a 'c'.

Comment: Yeah. If so then you just need to remove the `c` character from your string as stated above. Otherwise you get like `1+2c` which has a syntax error.