# Use of eval in Python, MATLAB, etc

Tags: python, matlab, eval

I do know that one shouldn't use `eval`. For all the obvious reasons (performance, maintainability, etc.). My question is more on the side – is there a legitimate use for it? Where one should use it rather than implement the code in another way.

Since it is implemented in several languages and can lead to bad programming style, I assume there is a reason why it's still available.

Comment: Nice question. I'm interested in seeing the answers.

Comment: @InbarRose I disagree. That question asks not "what's a legitimate use of eval" but only "is this specific use of eval legitimate". Consequently, the answers say that this use is bad and how it can be avoided, but not when it *should* be used.

Comment: [Is there ever a good reason to use eval()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826859/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-eval)

Comment: Why was the question changed from "Use of eval in Matlab" to "Python"?

Comment: Fixed the title. Maybe someone doesn't like Matlab. The [Wikipedia page on `eval`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Uses) describes several uses.

Comment: @horchler. Thank you for the link. I can see it for bootstrapping argument for compiled languages. But this this make sense for JIT or interpreted languages?

Answer (score 3):

First, here is [Mathwork's list of alternatives to eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

You could also be clever and use `eval()` in a compiled application to build your mCode interpreter, but the Matlab compiler doesn't allow that for obvious reasons.

Comment: +1 for the Mathworks link!

Comment: This is actually a nice route of thinking. But I'm not sure if this count's since it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2):

One place where I have found a reasonable use of `eval` is in obtaining small predicates of code that consumers of my software need to be able to supply as part of a parameter file.

For example, there might be an item called "Data" that has a location for reading and writing the data, but also requires some predicate applied to it upon load. In a Yaml file, this might look like:

```
Data:
    Name: CustomerID
    ReadLoc: some_server.some_table
    WriteLoc: write_server.write_table
    Predicate: "lambda x: x[:4]"
```

Upon loading and parsing the objects from Yaml, I can use `eval` to turn the predicate string into a callable lambda function. In this case, it implies that CustomerID is a long string and only the first 4 characters are needed in this particular instance.

Yaml offers some clunky ways to magically invoke object constructors (e.g. using something like `!Data` in my code above, and then having defined a class for `Data` in the code that appropriately uses Yaml hooks into the constructor). In fact, one of the biggest criticisms I have of the Yaml magic object construction is that it is effectively like making your whole parameter file into one giant `eval` statement. And this is very problematic if you need to validate things and if you need flexibility in the way multiple parts of the code absorb multiple parts of the parameter file. It also doesn't lend itself easily to templating with Mako, whereas my approach above makes that easy.

I think this simpler design which can be easily parsed with any XML tools is better, and using `eval` lets me allow the user to pass in whatever arbitrary callable they want.

A couple of notes on why this works in my case:

1. The users of the code are not Python programmers. They don't have the ability to write their own functions and then just pass a module location, function name, and argument signature (although, putting all that in a parameter file is another way to solve this that wouldn't rely on `eval` *if* the consumers can be trusted to write code.)
2. The users are responsible for their bad lambda functions. I can do some validation that `eval` works on the passed predicate, and maybe even create some tests on the fly or have a nice failure mode, but at the end of the day I am allowed to tell them that it's their job to supply valid predicates and to ensure the data can be manipulated with simple predicates. If this constraint wasn't in place, I'd have to shuck this for a different system.
3. The users of these parameter files compose a small group mostly willing to conform to conventions. If that weren't true, it would be risky that folks would hi-jack the predicate field to do many inappropriate things -- and this would be hard to guard against. On big projects, it would not be a great idea.

I don't know if my points apply very generally, but I would say that using `eval` to add flexibility to a parameter file is good if you can guarantee your users are a small group of convention-upholders (a rare feat, I know).

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB the `eval` function is useful when functions make use of the name of the input argument via the `inputname` function. For example, to overload the builtin `display` function (which is sensitive to the name of the input argument) the `eval` function is required. For example, to call the built in `display` from an overloaded `display` you would do

```
function display(X)
    eval([inputname(1), ' = X;']);
    eval(['builtin(''display'', ', inputname(1), ');']);
end
```

In MATLAB there is also `evalc`. From the documentation:

> T = evalc(S) is the same as EVAL(S) except that anything that would
>       normally be written to the command window, except for error messages,
>       is captured and returned in the character array T (lines in T are
>       separated by '\n' characters).

If you still consider this `eval`, then it is very powerful when dealing with closed source code that displays useful information in the command window and you need to capture and parse that output.