# Load large matrix from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a text file like :

```
[ 1, 2, 3; 
  2, 4, 5;
  2, 2, 2;
  8, 3, 3 ]
```

What is the quickest way to load this as a matrix in Octave/Matlab? I want to see this as a matrix with 4 rows and 3 cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the text file with your mouse over your workspace in MATLAB (the area where all your current variables are shown) and drop it there. This opens the "import" window:

[image: Import window]

Give the file a name (mine is currently "NewTextDocument2") and select IMPORT on the top right. MATLAB will take care of semicolons and brackets. If you want to have a function that does this, select "generate function" instead of IMPORT.

Comment: Is there a command which can load it? I have a lot of such files and need to do it programatically

Comment: Select "create function" instead of import. This will create a function for you that does the import. You can now change the function a little and have it accept the filename as an argument.

Comment: look at my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the simplest.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f', ...
    'Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne', 1);
fclose(fid);
DataMatrix = cat(2,C{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains only numbers you can use the [Matlab `load()` function](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/load.html). This function is often used to load `.mat` files. However it is capable of dealing with what matlab calls `ASCII` format files.

Say your file is purely textual, contains only numbers and is structured as follows:

```
filename.txt
  1 2 3 
  2 4 5
  2 2 2
  8 3 3
```

The load function will create a variable called `filename` containing your array:

```matlab
> load('filename.txt');
> filename = 
         [ 1, 2, 3; 
         2, 4, 5;
         2, 2, 2;
         8, 3, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and [really dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909609/use-of-eval-in-python-matlab-etc) approach using the [generally non-recommended](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) function `eval`:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
s = fscanf(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
eval(['dataMatrix = ' s ';']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with your current format of textfile.

**Use this function importfile.m:**

```matlab
function filename = importfile(filename, startRow, endRow)
delimiter = ',';
if nargin<=2
    startRow = 1;
    endRow = inf;
end

formatSpec = '%s%s%s%[^\n\r]';

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');

dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);
    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines', startRow(block)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    for col=1:length(dataArray)
        dataArray{col} = [dataArray{col};dataArrayBlock{col}];
    end
end

fclose(fileID);

raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = dataArray{col};
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));

for col=[1,2,3]
    rawData = dataArray{col};
    for row=1:size(rawData, 1);
        regexstr = '(?<prefix>.*?)(?<numbers>([-]*(\d+[\,]*)+[\.]{0,1}\d*[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1})|([-]*(\d+[\,]*)*[\.]{1,1}\d+[eEdD]{0,1}[-+]*\d*[i]{0,1}))(?<suffix>.*)';
        try
            result = regexp(rawData{row}, regexstr, 'names');
            numbers = result.numbers;

            invalidThousandsSeparator = false;
            if any(numbers==',');
                thousandsRegExp = '^\d+?(\,\d{3})*\.{0,1}\d*$';
                if isempty(regexp(thousandsRegExp, ',', 'once'));
                    numbers = NaN;
                    invalidThousandsSeparator = true;
                end
            end
            if ~invalidThousandsSeparator;
                numbers = textscan(strrep(numbers, ',', ''), '%f');
                numericData(row, col) = numbers{1};
                raw{row, col} = numbers{1};
            end
        catch me
        end
    end
end
```

filename = cell2mat(raw);

**How to use it:**

```matlab
>> importfile('file.txt',1,4)
```

ans =

```
     1     2     3
     2     4     5
     2     2     2
     8     3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

in Octave you could do

```
fid = fopen ("yourfile", "r");
x = str2num (char(fread(fid))');
fclose (fid)
```

(I don't know if this works in Matlab)